# What should a vegetarian student cook in a foreign country

Tags: nutrition

I have been facing this problem for quite a while. What should a vegetarian student cook and eat to avoid any significant Vitamin deficiency and to stay healthy. Please keep in mind that such a student faces money and time constraints.

The easily available options which I have found out by now are cooking rice, and maybe dal, in a rice cooker. And of course one can toast a bread and have it with butter or jam. But I am finding it very difficult to keep myself going with these options.

The common deficiency that a vegetarian faces are lack of protein and Vitamin D12. These are more or less offset by the intake of other green vegetables. But I have found out that the vegetables, which I eat, are not available in my area. So naturally I will not meet those nutrients demand of my body and in due time may develop some deficiency.

I have edited my question on the advice of comments I received. I agree this question is more suitable for cooking stackexchange site but this problem faced by vegetarians has far too many health influences for it to be neglected.

So I urge the reader to consider this problem as a serious one. But I understand that a non vegetarian may find it difficult to label this as a serious problem.

The country I am from is India and I have recently moved to Canada. It would be really nice if someone shed some light over this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome Parish! This is a really broad question and is likely to be closed for being too broad to answer reasonably. I would recommend adjusting it to ask for a specific nutrient like protein or another more narrow (and thus answerable) question.  It almost sounds like you're asking how to eat vegetarian in general, but I'm assuming you did prior to moving and are coming from a country with more vegetarian food variety into a more meat-and-potatoes environment.  Try adjusting it and you're more likely to get a good answer. :)

Comment: Adding on @DoctorWhom 's points, this question seems more related to Cooking.SE as it isn't about Health per se, but rather cooking in a foreign country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Cooking.SE

Comment: I actually think it could be a question about nutrient balance and adequate protein intake if it were phrased that way, which definitely is a health issue.  Dietician/nutritionist is a health profession and we address nutrient deficiencies in clinical medicine.  But as it is, which seems to ask about regional cuisine options, I would agree.

Comment: She hasn't edited it; voting to close/migrate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad and belongs in Cooking, unless OP edits to focus on a specific nutrient

Comment: Note: same question has been asked on Seasoned Advice and is on hold there because requests for nutrition advice are off topic. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84223/what-should-a-vegetarian-student-cook-in-a-foreign-country

Comment: Canada has lots of vegetables.  Expand the vegetables you eat.